# Program to Calculate Primes between 2 numbers - SPOJ Problem2

Tags: c++, logic, primes

This is in reference to the SPOJ Problem2 - http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

I am quoting it here -

**Problem** : 
Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!

*Input*

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

*Output*

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 // Prime Generator
 int cases;
 int z;

 cin >> cases;
 int lower[cases];
 int upper[cases];

 for (int l = 0; l < cases; l++) {
    cin >> lower[l];
    cin >> upper[l];
 }

 for (int n = 0; n < cases; n ++) {

    for (int i = lower[n]; i <= upper[n]; i++ ) {

        z = 1;
        for (int x = 2; x < i; x++) {
            if (i % x == 0) {
                z = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == 1) {
            z = 0;
        }

        if (z == 1) {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
 }
}
```

Why is this code not working? It is showing time limit exceeded.

Comment: You need a better algorithm.  Have you ever implemeted a [sieve of eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)?

Comment: I am relatively new to programming, but yes I am taking a look at sieve. And may I know the reason for the downvotes? I mean are you guys normally this hard on newbies?

Answer (score 0):

You should learn sieve method for generate prime between any number a and b where a-b<=1000000 so use this and it will be accepted .
Don't worry about votes just learn the concepts initially all faced this issue  so enjoy coding.